# Create Spiral Matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can any one help creating spiral matrix in matlab using only `loops` and `if else` conditions.

For example `n=5`, spiral matrix is:

```
17    16    15    14    13
18     5     4     3    12
19     6     1     2    11
20     7     8     9    10
21    22    23    24    25
```

Comment: [Whats wrong with this solution?](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/466188-how-do-i-generate-a-spiral-matrix-which-starts-from-first-element) Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: [That solution](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/466188-how-do-i-generate-a-spiral-matrix-which-starts-from-first-element) forms an inwards spiral, while above is one that goes outwards as the value increases. However, a slight modification in the code in the link will make it appropriate to form an outwards spiral.

Comment: @thewaywewalk it does not start from the middle, it starts from point (1,1) not teh middle of matrix

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
nn = input('');
n = floor(1+(nn)/2);
a = zeros(nn,nn);
i=n;j=n;m=1;br=true;
if rem(nn,2)==0
    j=n-1;
    nn=nn+2;
end
for p=1:2:nn
    k=0;
    while k<p-2
        k=k+1;
        a(i,j)=m;
        i=i-1;
        m=m+1;
    end
    k=0;
    while k<p-1
        k=k+1;
        a(i,j)=m;
        j=j-1;
        m=m+1;
    end
    k=0;
    while k<p-1
        if j<1
            br = false;
            break
        end
        k=k+1;
        a(i,j)=m;
        i=i+1;
        m=m+1;
    end
    if ~br
        break
    end
    k=0;
    while k<p
        k=k+1;
        a(i,j)=m;
        j=j+1;
        m=m+1;
    end
end
disp(a)
```

Here is a sample run:

```
Enter the number:

5

    17    16    15    14    13
    18     5     4     3    12
    19     6     1     2    11
    20     7     8     9    10
    21    22    23    24    25
```

Another one, this time using an even number:

```
Enter the number:

6

    36    35    34    33    32    31
    17    16    15    14    13    30
    18     5     4     3    12    29
    19     6     1     2    11    28
    20     7     8     9    10    27
    21    22    23    24    25    26
```

Explanation: It starts with the central cell in the case of an odd number as input, and the bottom-left central cell in the case of an even input. It then, starting with 1 as the value and taking one circulation at a time, moves outwards, traverses right, up, left, down, and right again, incrementing the value to be assigned with each step, until the entire matrix is full.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function `spiral` in your MATLAB installation, doing exactly what you want.

```
>> spiral(5)

ans =

    21    22    23    24    25
    20     7     8     9    10
    19     6     1     2    11
    18     5     4     3    12
    17    16    15    14    13
```

You can view the source code typing `edit spiral`

Comment: Good to know MATLAB has this built-in function, awesome! +1

Comment: For the same result as that of the OP, you can combine it with `flipud`. i.e. `flipud(spiral(5))`

Comment: @Daniel I know there is spiral but I want to implement it as I mentioend using loops and conditions !! thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the code? It uses a loop and two conditions...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom function `SpiralMatrix` to construct the spiral matrix as your requested

```
function M = SpiralMatrix(n)
  M = zeros(n);
  %  start from element M(1,1)
  i = 1;
  j = 1;
  s = 1; % first element assigned to M(1,1)
  M(i,j) = s;
  while true
    %  fill row from left to right
    idx = find(M(i,:)==0,1,'last');
    M(i,j:idx) = s + (0:(idx-j));
    s = s + idx - j;
    j = idx;

    %  fill column from top to bottom
    idx = find(M(:,j)==0,1,'last');
    M(i:idx,j) = s + (0:(idx-i));
    s = s + idx - i;
    i = idx;

    %  fill row from right to left
    idx = find(M(i,:)==0,1,'first');
    M(i,j:-1:idx) = s + (0:(j-idx));
    s = s + j - idx;
    j = idx;

    % fill column from bottom to top
    idx = find(M(:,j)==0,1,'first');
    M(i:-1:idx,j) = s + (0:(i-idx));
    s = s + i-idx;
    i = idx;

    % break if matrix if fully filled       
    if nnz(M) == n^2
      break;
    end
  end
  M = n^2+1-fliplr(flipud(M));
end
```

such that

```
>> SpiralMatrix(5)
ans =

   17   16   15   14   13
   18    5    4    3   12
   19    6    1    2   11
   20    7    8    9   10
   21   22   23   24   25

>> SpiralMatrix(7)
ans =

   37   36   35   34   33   32   31
   38   17   16   15   14   13   30
   39   18    5    4    3   12   29
   40   19    6    1    2   11   28
   41   20    7    8    9   10   27
   42   21   22   23   24   25   26
   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
```